# Add an external library to symfony

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I'm trying to add an external library to symfony.
I've tried this on the app/autoload.php:

```
$loader->add('LibCokeId',__DIR__ . '/../vendor/libcokeid/libcokeid/lib');
```

However when I try to use it in a controller:

```
use libCokeId\LibCokeId

Libcokeid::init()
```

I get the miss use statement error.

Any help?

Comment: how do you install the library? It doesn't exists on packagist? It have a repo on github? Have a custom autoloader? Can you specify the complete error? Sorry for too many questions :)

Comment: @Matteo it is not on packagist and has no composer nor github repo. The error is: Attempted to load class "LibCokeId" from namespace "libCokeId".
Did you forget a "use" statement for "LibCokeId\LibCokeId"?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the situation where you have a library that doesn't use composer and you can't retrieve it from packagist, you can manipulate the [Composer autoload](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading).

Simply add the class in the `composer.json` files, as example:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "": "src/" },
    "files": [
        "vendor/folder/my_custom_lib/myFiles.php",
        "vendor/libcokeid/libcokeid/lib/libCokeId/LibCokeId.php"
    ]
},
```

OR you can Autoload the whole folder in `composer.json`:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "": "src/" },
    "classmap": [
        "vendor/libcokeid/libcokeid/lib"
    ],
},
```

Remember to make a composer install after setting this.

Hope this help.

Comment: This woked perfect. Remember to make a composer install after setting this. Thanks

Comment: I will add the comment from @SergioGonzález as it made the difference for me :)

Comment: Will it just install this library, that means it wont touch the previous packages ?