# Install AWS-SDK into Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, aws-sdk

I need to use AWS-SDK in my Symfony platform version 2 but getting the error :

Fatal error: Class 'Aws\S3\S3Client' not found

The steps I followed:

- composer require aws/aws-sdk-php.
- Registrer a namespace into the autoload.file:

  ```
  'aws-sdk-php'      => __DIR__.'/../vendor/aws'
  ```
- Add to composer.json:

  ```
  "autoload": {
          "psr-0": { "": "src/" },
          "classmap": [
              "vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src"
          ]
      }
  ```
- Execute composer install.

  In my class code I write:

  ```
  use Aws\S3\S3Client;
  ```

And when :

```
  // Instance an Amazon S3 client.
   $p1 = array('version' => 'latest',
            'region'  => 'us-west-2');
   $s3 = new S3Client($p1);
```

Error appears:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Aws\S3\S3Client' not found
```

Thank you!

Comment: You should not need to add the autoload information as this is done automatically when you install the package through composer. Have you tried it without that step?

Comment: Yes I did. What's more, I did that step trying to find solve the same error, because I read it: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40763430/add-an-external-library-to-symfony 
 I will get rid these lines off from composer.json.

Comment: Any other suggestion?

Comment: Did you try `$s3Client = (new \Aws\Sdk(....))->createS3();`? Check [Uploading files to AWS S3 buckets within Symfony application using PHP AWS SDK](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/8eqs/uploading-files-to-aws-s3-buckets-within-symfony-application-using-php-aws-sdk)

Comment: Still not working. I decided to upgrade Symfony version in order to use https://packagist.org/packages/aws/aws-sdk-php-symfony. Thank you all!