# Problems to include external library without composer

Tags: php, symfony4

I have downloaded an external Php library, which is mandatory to work with its API.

That library does not meet the standards psr-0 and psr-4, so it is impossible to load it as a service, nor with an autoloader.

Then I have been forced to load that library, as it has been done a lifetime. With an include ('file.php').

The problem is that in this way, it fails to load the file and I don't know the reason ...

The path where the file I want to upload is is as follows: 'src/Service/Libraries/PapApi.php'

This is what I am doing:

```
<?php

namespace App\Service\Apiclient;

include_once('../Libraries/PapApi.php');

class PostAffiliateService
{

    private $session;

    private $user       = 'user@';
    private $pass       = 'pass@';
    private $baseUrl    = 'http://host.postaffiliatepro.com/scripts/server.php';

    public function __construct() {

        $this->session = new \Pap_Api_Session($this->baseUrl);

        if ($this->session->login($this->user,$this->pass)) {
            throw new \Exception('Error to login PostAffiliatePro : ' .$this->session->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

When running by console :  php bin/console cache:clear

It returns the following error :

> In FileLoader.php line 166
>   Warning: include_once(../Libraries/PapApi.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mercurio/config/services.yaml (which is loaded in resource "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mercurio/config/services.yaml"). In PostAffiliateService.php line 5:
>                                                                                                   Warning: include_once(../Libraries/PapApi.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: Put the class outside of the `src` directory then. Also don't require by relative directory but use absolute path instead (using the `__DIR__` constant).

Comment: Is this any help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40763430/add-an-external-library-to-symfony

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add an external library to symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40763430/add-an-external-library-to-symfony)

Comment: I got it at the end, putting the class inside the src, doing this:

include_once (__ DIR __. '/ .. / Libraries / PapApi.php') ;. Thanks All!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use an absolute path to the file you want to include or use **DIR** in include_once. This is because you run script not from directory, your include expect it to be.

Comment: Is this the solution. 

include_once(__DIR__.'/../Libraries/PapApi.php');

Thanks!!